# How do I access the autofac container in ASP.NET MVC3 controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

I would like to resolve a dependency using a named parameter in an MVC controller. If I can access the Autofac container I should be able to do it like so:

```
var service = Container.Resolve<IService>(
    new NamedParameter("fileExtension", dupExt)
);
```

I can't find out how to access the AutoFac container. Is there a global reference to the container that I can use or is there another way to use named parameters?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I've just discovered I can use IComponentContext for the same thing. You can inject an instance of IComponentContext into the controller.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _icoContext;

    public void MyController(IComponentContext icoContext)
    {
        _icoContext= icoContext;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var service = _icoContext.Resolve<IService>(
            new NamedParameter("ext", "txt")
        );
    }
}
```

I've found some good advice on getting global access to the container in this question:
[Autofac in web applications, where should I store the container for easy access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644747/autofac-in-web-applications-where-should-i-store-the-container-for-easy-access)

I've also found how to get access to the dependency resolver globally here: [Global access to autofac dependency resolver in ASP.NET MVC3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777830/global-access-to-autofac-dependency-resolver-in-asp-net-mvc3)

Comment: You should't do that. It's a bad practice. Instead of service locator approach it's better to do constructor injection. Simply inject IService to the constructor and use the injected instace as a class fiel

Comment: How can I use named parameters with that approach?

Comment: You can get something similar using Factory delegate: http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/DelegateFactories

Answer (score 12):

```
AutofacDependencyResolver.Current.ApplicationContainer

.Resolve

.ResolveNamed

.ResolveKeyed

.....
```

Comment: You might want to flesh out your response a bit. Just posting a few names is not that helpful for most people.

Comment: I think his answer is actually helping. I got my problem resolved with this answer.

Comment: Well, I did not. I think this answer should be improved.